# Power BI show all fields in Matrix

Tags: powerbi, report, dax

I have the below data

```
Item1   Item2   Item3   Item4   Item5   Item6   Item7   Item8   Item9   Item10  Item11  Item12  Item13  Item14  Item15  Item16  Item17  Amount
Europe  Turkey  Adana   01/01/2016  Clerical    89.99   25/01/2016  3   Bib-Shorts  Men's Bib-Shorts, M 1   1457.99 42445   1   Road Bikes  Road-450 Red, 58    A   192
Europe  Turkey  Adana   01/01/2016  Management  37.99   05/01/2016  3   Gloves  Full-Finger Gloves, S   1   69.99   42487   3   Shorts  Women's Mountain Shorts, L  B   120
Europe  Turkey  Adana   01/01/2016  Manual  333.42  24/01/2016  2   Touring Frames  LL Touring Frame - Blue, 50 1   348.76  42465   2   Mountain Frames ML Mountain Frame - Black, 44   C   343
```

in excel see screenshot
[image]
I created a matrix report in power BI to show all columns and use amount as a measure

The problem is that i cannot see all the columns even though I use the slide bar what i can see is static
[image]

I can only see the first Nine items irrespective of what I do like using the slide. is there anything i can to to be able to scroll and see all the columns. if I reduce the font size they text become too small to read

Please note I turned off the Subtotal and Applied steps

see the dataset in GDrive
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17hsLWF2WpuKB78z6vjNJqEkmKO6HwJ936TlIXbB3qJI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share the report with small sample data set?

Comment: @mkRabbani I have added a sample dataset to it on googlesheet with the link

Comment: There is no issue with data I guess. May be something in your Metrix setup.

Comment: @mkRabbani i do beleieve it has to do with the matrix set up. I am wondering if there is a way i can switch something on or off to be able to slide through the visual